# Using a low-latency kernel breaks my screen resolution; how can I fix it?

Tags: kernel, display-resolution

I started using Ubuntu 16.04.02 recently.

I have to use the low-latency kernel 4.7 or 4.8 because it's a requirement of open-air-interface(OAI).

I downloaded low-latency kernel 4.8.0. When I run it, my screen resolution is broken as shown below.

[image: Displays interface]

How can I get back to my previous setting (1920 x 1080)?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and a NVidia GPU and solved it by installing the following packages:

```sh
sudo apt install linux-image-5.19.0-1018-lowlatency
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.19.0-1018-lowlatency
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-525
sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1018-lowlatency
sudo apt install linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1018-lowlatency
```

Be sure the kernel version (here `5.19.0-1018`) and the driver version (here `525`) match each other in these packages' names.

You can find available kernel versions this way:

```sh
apt-cache search "linux-image-[^a-z]+-lowlatency"
```

You can find available nvidia-driver version this way:

```sh
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-<tab>
```

In both case I go with the most recent available versions.